# Correct Json Structure for IOS Swift with Rest API

Tags: json, rest, object

What is correct JSON structure to get from IOS swift device where multiple occurrence of the info is need to be store. I have to store multiple address of a person out of which one is current where he is living. How should i accepts current occupancy in case of IOS app written in swift. I have used "iscurrent" for checking current and previous occupancy. Also please suggest what is the correct way to send this json information in get API. I am using below for post as well as get. In get sending current occupancy always on top.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "address": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "suburb": "string",
      "postcode": "string",
      "moveindate": "string",
      "landlordname": "string",
      "landlordemail": "string",
      "iscurrent": 0,
      "occid": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Some suggested me to send as below after saving.

```
{
  "items": 
    "iscurrent" = {
      "address": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "suburb": "string",
      "postcode": "string",
      "moveindate": "string",
      "landlordname": "string",
      "landlordemail": "string",
      "occid": 1
    },
  "previous" = [{
      "address": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "suburb": "string",
      "postcode": "string",
      "moveindate": "string",
      "landlordname": "string",
      "landlordemail": "string",
      "occid": 2
    },{
      "address": "string",
      "city": "string",
      "suburb": "string",
      "postcode": "string",
      "moveindate": "string",
      "landlordname": "string",
      "landlordemail": "string",
      "occid": 3
    },
   ]

}
```

Comment: Not really sure what your question is or if it has to do with swift or iOS when you make your request and get your JSON you decide how you handle it, no matter how you want to structure it (boolean to set occupancy or splitting the results into 2). Personally I'd go for the boolean because it makes it easier to change and for JSON parsing I like to use SwiftyJSON

Comment: Thanks @JamesWoodrow , I know it does not depends on IOS, But IOS developer suggested, The first way is not correct for IOS swift code. So i asked the same here as i am back end developer

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be correct for swift code, unless it's just that the already existing code requires it's JSON in that format and so he's telling you that. But I wouldn't be able to say what is a right way and what is a wrong way really both seem correct to me although I prefer the one that mimic's the database on the backend the closest in its form, which would be the first one, but I suppose everyone does it however they prefer you should probably talk about this more with colleague to understand why he wants it in that format.

Comment: Thanks @JamesWoodrow for your point of view, lets see what others think of t.